# Tab autocomplete in latex using sublime text

Tags: sublime-text, latextools, code-snippets

I wrote a snippet for Sublime text that does the following:

```
\begin{lemma}

\end{lemma}
```

and puts the cursor between them. Which works fine. However, if I want to use <kbd>TAB</kbd> inside the environment - lets say I want to complete `enum` - the cursor moves to the line after `\end{lemma}` and I end up with this

```
\begin{lemma}
    enum
 \end{lemma}
```

the cursor is here now.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?

This is the snippet

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
\begin{lemma}
$1
\end{lemma}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>lem</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.tex</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: It would be useful to add your snippet. I assume you use a `$1` inside your lemma. You can change it to `$0` to end the snippet inside the environment instead of having a field inside and end it after the environment.

Comment: @r-stein yes you are right I'm using $1. I edited the question to include the snippet.

Comment: if you are using latextools package in sublime and type `begin` there is already a similar snippet